# Change End Of Line git configuration

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, newline, eol

So right now I'm working in a proyect with another college and he uses mac and I use windows, so we are having trouble with the EOL (End Of Line) of our files. We decided, we wanted all files to be LF. For him that's no problem, because he is using a mac, but I must change all my files from **CRLF** to **LF**, which I have already done, also I have set a config that everytime when I add a new file it starts as **LF**. The problem is that when I want to commit changes to our repo, it gives me this warning.

```
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory warning: LF will be replaced by 
CRLF in tsconfig.build.json.
```

What I want to achieve? I want to disable this "automatic" replacement by github. I don't want my files to be replaced by **CRLF**, I want all my files to be **LF** at all times. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First some important terminology notes:  *GitHub* never replace *anything*.  They literally can't.  Don't worry about GitHub here; they are irrelevant.  *Do* worry about *your own Git*, which—aside from starting with the same three letters—has very little to do with GitHub.  GitHub are a *hosting provider* where you can store and access Git repositories.  *Git* is software that implements a Version Control System.

*Your Git* is where the problem is and/or should be solved.  Well, your Git, and your friends's or colleague's Git, and so on, depending on what systems they use.  Your file editors may also play roles, but Git can and will override them, if you set it up to do so.

> i want all my files to be LF at all times.

You mention Visual Studio Code, which might also have its own method of messing about with your files.  You can investigate this and configure it if it suits your purposes.  This answer only concerns Git itself.

#### What to set in `.gitattributes`

To make sure that newly added or updated files get and see LF-only line endings, modify your existing `.gitattributes` files to list the file names or patterns you want affected and include:

```
<pattern> text eol=lf
```

The *`pattern`* part here can include things like `*.json` or `*.sh` or even just `*` (which matches all file names).

If you don't have a `.gitattributes` file, just create one.  Make sure it contains plain text, preferably simple ASCII or UTF-8 without byte-order-markers.

#### What this `* text eol=lf` line means

As noted above, the first part is a pattern: it's the set of files that the rest of the line applies to.  You can list more than one pattern, or list the same pattern more than once, by including multiple lines.  The *last* matching pattern will generally override earlier ones.<sup>1</sup>

The `text` part tells Git that this file is *text*, i.e., edit-able stuff made up of lines, as opposed to binary files, that Git can't assume contains text.  This enables *end of line conversion* on the file.<sup>2</sup>

The `eol=lf` tells Git *what the ends of lines should look like*.  The `lf` here means *use line-feed endings*, as opposed to the CRLF line endings that Windows programs often seem to prefer or require.

The other value you can set for `eol` is `eol=crlf`, but given your statement above, you don't want that.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is how it works in `.gitignore` as well.  But, in `.gitattributes` files, this can get complicated, since each line can set different things.  For instance, you can write:

```
* text
*.bin -text
```

The `-text` overrides the `text`, so the last line takes precedence, but *only for files whose name ends with `.bin`*.  But you could also write:

```
* text zorg
*.bin -text
```

then you've set the `zorg` attribute for *all* files, including `*.bin` files.  The `-text` *unsets* `text` for `*.bin`, but leaves `zorg` set.

<sup>2</sup>Technically, you can leave the `text` part out entirely if you use the `eol=lf` part.  Setting `eol` to some value implies setting `text`.  [The gitattributes documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) uses `text eol=lf` in an example, though, so that seems to be *de rigueur*.

---

#### Don't use `core.autocrlf`

Very old versions of Git used `core.autocrlf`, `core.eol`, and other similar `core` settings to do this sort of thing.  Along with this, you can—but should not—use `text=auto` in a `.gitattributes` line.  This tells Git to *guess* whether the file contains text, and therefore lines whose line-endings can be changed, or binary (and therefore should not have its line-endings messed with, as they merely coincidentally *resemble* line endings, but are actually precious binary data).

The warning you're seeing has to do with this stuff.  If Git plans to mess with some file, and the *way* Git plans to mess with the file looks a little suspicious to Git, Git warns you about it.

#### The underlying mechanism

There may come a time—or maybe it has already come—where you want to see what's in the repository itself, rather than the files you work with.  You might wonder what this statement means.  After all, isn't the repository the collection of the files you work with?  But the answer is: no, it's not!

**Git is all about commits.**  What a Git repository contains and uses is, at least for the most part, *commits*.  While a commit *contains* files, a commit is not, itself, a file, nor is it the files it contains.  A commit is its own thing.  It's something real, and it's a unit—well, mostly *the* unit—that your Git passes around to other Gits, and vice versa.

Every commit has a unique number.  That's not a unique number within *your* repository, but rather, a globally or universally unique number: a [UUID or GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).  To make sure each ID is truly unique to each particular commit, Git assigns very long and random-looking hash IDs to the commits.  These are, in effect, the true names of each commit.  Your Git gets together with some other Git, and the two share commits by sharing these IDs.  If your Git has some ID they don't, that means your Git has some *commit* they don't, and vice versa.

This ID is in fact a cryptographic checksum of all the data that go into the commit.  For this reason, no part of *any* commit can *ever change*, once the commit is made.  This is why you need not worry about GitHub.  You make the commits on your computer, and from then on, nothing—not even Git itself—can *change* them.  They are completely, totally read-only.  Any line endings inside any file inside any commit are that way *forever*—along with the rest of that line, and all the other lines, in that file.  The files inside each commit are all frozen for all time.

So, a commit contains files—that's its main data, really—along with some other *metadata* that we won't go into in this answer.  The files in the commit are frozen for all time, along with the metadata.  They're also stored in a de-duplicated format that only Git itself can *read*.  These two factors make the files quite useless for getting any real work done, because:

- we need to be able to *read* the files (in programs, in our editors, and so on), and
- we need to be able to *change* the files, to do new work.

What this means is that to use the files from some commit, Git must *extract* the files.  When it does so, it puts the extracted files in a work area.  Git calls this work area your *working tree* or *work-tree*.  This is quite simple: it's where you do your work.

The files you work on, in your working tree, are not *Git's* files.  The committed files are inside some commit.  Those can't be changed.  Git's files are elsewhere.  The work-tree files are *yours*, and are not inside Git at all.

**Because Git has to extract files** before you can see them and use them, this is an ideal place to take files that have LF-only line endings, and turn them into CRLF-ended files for you to see and work on/with.  If you choose to have Git mess with line endings, Git will try to store files with LF-only line endings at all times, and convert them to CRLF endings during the extraction process.

**Because Git has to compress files into its frozen format** before it can put any *new or changed file* into a commit, this is an ideal place to take files that have CRLF line endings, and turn them into files that have LF-only line endings, before storing them inside a new commit.  If you choose to have Git mess with line endings, Git will always convert the lines to LF-only lines when replacing a file's content with new content.

**The mechanism for this works on the whole file.**  When you use `git add`—which you must do if you've updated some file<sup>3</sup>—Git will, at that time, do the line ending conversion *and* compress the file into the frozen format, ready to be committed.<sup>4</sup>  Similarly, when you use `git checkout` to switch from one commit to another, Git has to *remove from your work-tree* any file that is different (or gone entirely!) in the new commit you're switching *to*, and replace it with the file taken out of that commit.  It then expands out the committed file into a usable one in your work-tree, and while doing so, can replace LF-only line endings with CRLF line endings.

The especially-tricky part of this is, as noted in footnote 4, that Git works hard not to bother with files that *didn't* change.  This all *assumes* that whatever `eol=` setting might have applied before, still applies now.  So, sometimes, when you *change* the `eol=` setting, you have to erase Git's index to invalidate it, or touch all your files in your work-tree, or use `git add --renormalize`, if your Git is new enough to have the "renormalize" option.

What this boils down to in practice is that if you *change* the `eol=` setting, you may want to run `git add --renormalize --all` or similar.  If you don't have it, there are some fairly ugly workarounds, but the best thing to do is probably to upgrade your Git version.

---

<sup>3</sup>While you *can* use `git commit -a` or `git commit --include` and a list of file names, the way this works internally is, more or less, to run `git add` on those files.  There's a lot to the *more or less* part but this answer won't go into those details.

<sup>4</sup>The mechanism for *this* involves what Git calls, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or—rarely these days—the *cache*.  These three terms all refer to the same thing.  The cache aspect of this thing tries to keep track of which files you might have actually changed in your work-tree, and which ones you definitely *didn't* change in your work-tree.  This lets Git leave these files alone, as you change from commit to commit, speeding Git up.  It also lets `git add` *skip* adding some files, speeding Git up.

Comment: That was a tremendous amount of detail!  Thanks so much for the in-depth response.